# In an autotools project how do I specify the installation order of libraries?

Tags: gnu, autotools, libtool

I find this issue is seen only when I am building shared libraries.

Here is the exact issue:
In main.mk:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES += libone.la
libone_la_LIBADD =
```

In dir-one/automake.mk:

```
...
libone_la_LIBADD += libtwo.la
...
```

In dir-two/automake.mk:

```
...
libone_la_LIBADD += libthree.la
...
```

In Makefile.am:

```
include main.mk
include dir-one/automake.mk
include dir-two/automake.mk
```

While make runs fine, `make install` complains that linker cannot find `-ltwo` and `-lthree`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES += libthree.la libtwo.la libone.la
```

should give you the right install order.